# Failures when running Keycloak Testsuite with external Keycloak server

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to run the keycloak Testsuite against an external  Keycloak server that I have created.
I am using the base tests in the integration-arquillian using the following commands

`mvn -f testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/pom.xml clean install --log-file My_testsuite_integration_logs06.txt -Pauth-server-wildfly -Dauth.server.ssl.required=false -Dpageload.timeout=3600000 -Dauth.server.host={my-server-details} -Dauth.server.http.port={port#}`

It works when I am using the embedded tests, but when I add the server details as stated in the HOW-TO-RUN.md file its failing.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/stage/testsuite/integration-arquillian

========

**[INFO] Running org.keycloak.testsuite.account.AccountFormServiceTest
11:56:38,313 ERROR [org.keycloak.testsuite.account.AccountFormServiceTest] [AccountFormServiceTest] null() FAILED
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.keycloak.testsuite.account.AccountFormServiceTest
[ERROR] org.keycloak.testsuite.account.AccountFormServiceTest  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Arquillian initialization has already been attempted, but failed. See previous exceptions for cause
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.handleSuiteLevelFailure(AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.java:36)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.AdaptorManager.initializeAdaptor(AdaptorManager.java:16)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.initializeAdaptor(AdaptorManagerWithNotifier.java:19)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:109)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: The java process starting the managed server exited unexpectedly with code [2]
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:152)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:123)
...**

==
Getting similiar to above for all my tests and not sure why it is failing.

any help be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the issue is quiet vague, but have you tried

```
mvn -f testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/pom.xml clean install -Pauth-server-remote -Dauth.server.ssl.required=false Dpageload.timeout=3600000 -Dauth.server.host={my-server-details} -Dauth.server.http.port={port#}
```

The Profile defined could be where the issue lies.

If you take a look at the documentation https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/stage/testsuite/integration-arquillian/HOW-TO-RUN.md#remote-server-tests
It shows you how to build the keycloak server from source and run it (remote or local) and the above command is then used to run tests against this solution. Take note of

"The testsuite currently doesn't work with port 80."